# Cannot set current date in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, web

I want to set current date in `@Html.EditorFor` But I don't know the correct syntax.

What syntax that can I use to set current date?

I expect that would set automatically when run the page but it wasn't showed.

Comment: Welcom to stackOverflow , You need to bind model to view , Set property of 'abc' value @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.abc) before load the view.

Comment: could you mind to give the example, i got clueless

Answer (score 0):

You can use js for this. For Example:

```
<div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp;</i>@DateTime.Now.Day/@DateTime.Now.Month/@DateTime.Now.Year -  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;<i id="time"></i></p>
 </div>
```

Script :

```
startTime = function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
            h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
    }
    setInterval(startTime, 1000);
```

If you need to datetime value when the page post, you can set the value datetime.now in httppost method. Or if you just want to show datetime.now from httpget index method to view check link please. [Current date and time - Default in MVC razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112127/current-date-and-time-default-in-mvc-razor).

Another easy way:

```
@{Model.CurrentDate = Datetime.Now;}
@Html.EditFor(x => x.CurrentDate)
```