# Display Current DateTime in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want display the current time as the data for the table in database. Below the code I have write some code for it but the text box for date still empty.

This is my class

```
    public class OrderMetaData
    {
        public string OrderAddress { get; set; }
        public int OrderPrice { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        private DateTime? CurrentDate;
        [Display(Name = "Order Date:")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate
        {
            get { return CurrentDate ?? DateTime.Today; }
            set { CurrentDate = value; }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Chicken Chop with Black Pepper Sauce")]
        public int A_ChickenChop_BP { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Chicken Chop with Mushroom Sauce")]
        public int A_ChickenChop_M { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Spaghetti in Angel Hair")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_AH { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Spaghetti in Penne")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_P { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Spaghetti in Shells")]
        public int A_Spaghetti_S { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Chicken Rice with chicken breast part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_CB { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Chicken Rice with chicken wing part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_CW { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Chicken Rice with drumstick part")]
        public int A_ChickenRice_D { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Non-Spicy Wantan Mee")]
        public int A_WantanMee_NS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount of Spicy Wantan Mee")]
        public int A_WantanMee_IS { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my controller

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult PlaceOrder(Order orderDetail)
        {
            String message = "";
            using (myDatabaseEntities1 myDatabase1 = new myDatabaseEntities1())
            {
                orderDetail.OrderDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                //WF
                Double PriceOfF1 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_BP.GetValueOrDefault()) * 14.9;
                Double PriceOfF2 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_ChickenChop_M.GetValueOrDefault()) * 14.9;
                Double PriceOfF3 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_AH.GetValueOrDefault()) * 10.9;
                Double PriceOfF4 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_P.GetValueOrDefault()) * 10.9;
                Double PriceOfF5 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_Spaghetti_S.GetValueOrDefault()) * 10.9;
                //CF
                Double PriceOfF6 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CB.GetValueOrDefault()) * 6.9;
                Double PriceOfF7 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_CW.GetValueOrDefault()) * 6.9;
                Double PriceOfF8 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_ChickenRice_D.GetValueOrDefault()) * 6.9;
                Double PriceOfF9 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_WantanMee_NS.GetValueOrDefault()) * 6.9;
                Double PriceOfF10 = Convert.ToDouble(orderDetail.A_WantanMee_IS.GetValueOrDefault()) * 6.9;

                Double T_Price = orderDetail.OrderPrice;

                T_Price = PriceOfF1 + PriceOfF2 + PriceOfF3 + PriceOfF4 + PriceOfF5 +
                    PriceOfF6 + PriceOfF7 + PriceOfF8 + PriceOfF9 + PriceOfF10;

                if (T_Price > 1)
                {
                    myDatabase1.Orders.Add(orderDetail);
                    myDatabase1.SaveChanges();
                    message = "The order has been placed";
                    orderDetail.IsPlaced = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Please select at least one of the food";
                    orderDetail.IsPlaced = false;
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View(orderDetail);
        }
```

I have write the code in the controller as `orderDetail.OrderDate = System.DateTime.Now;` and inside the class as

```
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        private DateTime? CurrentDate;
        [Display(Name = "Order Date:")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate
        {
            get { return CurrentDate ?? DateTime.Today; }
            set { CurrentDate = value; }
        }
```

Below the code is my view code

```
@model Food_Founder.Models.Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PlaceOrder";
}

<h2>PlaceOrder</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @ViewBag.Message
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Order</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_BP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_BP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_BP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_M, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_M, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ChickenChop_M, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_AH, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_AH, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_AH, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_P, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_P, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_P, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_S, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_S, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_Spaghetti_S, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CW, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CW, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_CW, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_D, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_D, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ChickenRice_D, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_NS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_NS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_NS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_IS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_IS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "0"  } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_WantanMee_IS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsPlaced, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsPlaced)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsPlaced, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the images of that view is here
[image]

As I always use my style sheet so I didn't use the bootstrap and I haven't modify the view page with my style sheet.
However, my output still didn't show the current date inside the text box. This problem I have see on this post and follow it [Current date and time - Default in MVC razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112127/current-date-and-time-default-in-mvc-razor). Where is the mistake I make?

Comment: Your CurrentDate property is nullable so I believe you have to do something like this: get { if (CurrentDate.HasValue){ return CurrentDate; } else { return DateTime.Today; }

Comment: @user10728126 No... Still can't work without any error. The text box still blank.

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: @user10728126 Ya, I just post it with code and image

Comment: Your bound model shows @model Food_Founder.Models.Order yet the model you posted is titled OrderMetaData. If you want the OrderMetaData class to be bound to your view, you must change the model in the view to something like this if the namespace is the same: "@model Food_Founder.Models.OrderMetaData"

Answer (score 0):

```
In your OrderMetaData Class You can use as,


`[DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [Display(Name = "Order Date")]
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
 private DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } `
```

and in view class

```
 `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderMetaData.OrderDate )`

It worked for me
```

Comment: It can't work and it show 'Order' does not contain a definition for 'OrderMetaData' and no accessible extension method 'OrderMetaData' accepting a first argument of type 'Order' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in your action Method that don't return instance of model so model is null and you can't see anything in textbox.

change your action like this :

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PlaceOrder()
{
    var model=new OrderMetaData();
    return View(model);
}
```

and also change model in view from this :

```
@model Food_Founder.Models.Order
```

to this :

```
@model Food_Founder.Models.OrderMetaData
```

then change "post method" to get OrderMetaData model like this :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult PlaceOrder(OrderMetaData orderDetail)
        {
```

and then it work properly.

I hope it been helpful .

Comment: It can't work. It show ```Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Food_Founder.Models.OrderMetaData' to 'Food_Founder.Models.Order' Food_Founder```

Answer (score -1):

Debug the code and check the value **orderDetail.OrderDate = System.DateTime.Now;** is null or current date assigning correctly?

Comment: The current date is assigning correctly but it didn't show up on the view page.

Comment: Although a useful info, I think this would fit more in a comment section, right under the question, simply because it provides a suggestion and not an actual solution to the problem.